# make NSTableView row stay selected Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, swift4, nstableview

how would I go about making a previously selectedRow of an NSTableView stay selected after the user presses a button calling a method to work with that selectedRow?

It worked in a previous programm looking like this:

[image: selectedRow stays selected]

selecting it gives it the OSX selection color, clicking the save button makes the textField becomeFirstResponder() which makes the row go grey automatically and doesnt change the selectedRow property. This is not done by my code, so im happy it just works.

Now in a similar program I want to achieve exactly this, but after clicking a button (calling a method making the textField becomeFirstResponder()) the  visual selection is gone and also the tableView property selectedRow goes back to -1 (no row selected).

I tried a lot of ideas, most answers online are objective-C. Here is my most recent code (beeing called by the same button and pretty much faking what worked automatically before):

the NSTableViewAction method and the selectedRowCache variable:

```
var selectedRowCache = -1

@IBAction func alarmDataTableView(_ sender: NSTableView) {

    selectedRowCache = alarmDataTableView.selectedRow

}
```

the buttonAction:

```
@IBAction func editAlarmButton(_ sender: NSButton) {

    let row = alarmDataTableView.rowView(atRow: self.selectedRowCache,      makeIfNecessary: false)

    row?.backgroundColor = .blue

}
```

the selectedRowCache is just a variable that saves the selectedRow whenever the user selects a row (i dont want this).

no with this code the background color of the row doesnt do a thing (besides losing its selection after the button method is called).

the NSTableView is view based.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try to create a minimal action method which demonstrates the issue and post the code.

Comment: i updated the code. hope that is enough. thank you

Comment: This might be sidestepping the issue a little but have you tried making the tableview not allow an empty selection? Not sure how that fits in with your UI requirements...

Comment: Wait, are you trying to set the tableview selection by setting the background color of the row view? What you are doing in the `editAlarmButton` function looks suspicious to me. If you want to set the selected row of the table, just call `alarmDataTableView.selectRowIndexes(...)`, don't mess with the row view.

Comment: nono, the selection process itself works, not as i want it to (i.e. as it worked in the other programm), but it works. now i either make it work like it did before (grey row color for selectedRow) or i make it color the selected row programmatically ( which is what i tried with the .blue). i prefer the first solution. this is just UX. no logic. oh and what do you mean by "not allow empty selection"?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1535902-allowsemptyselection ...there's also a setting for it in IB in the inspector.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to why you are setting the backgroundColor of the row view, the background color of the row is handled by the tableview automatically based on the selected index (gray/blue being the focused/unfocused state). You mentioned the selection disappearing, that could be because the tableview is being reloaded. When that happens, anything you change on the row view or just about any other view gets blown away in addition to the selection indexes. You have to manually save and restore the selection indexes when you reload the table.

Comment: thank you, now for some reason the 'forced' selection always jumps to row 0 (logic works fine, again: only UX). but this is going in the right way. in general: how to achieve that light grey rowcolor? where is that property? would love to actually understand this.

Comment: because the tableView doesnt handle it the way i want it to and i dont know why (would love to know why). so my take on it is to fake the tableview behavior (the rows onfocused state) (knowing this is not the right way to go). now this got me curious both in why the tableview doesnt work as expected and in how to fake it.

Comment: okay i found it. you were right and i was blind. the buttonAction method is rather huge (button has different functions and changes title) and there was indeed a .reloadData() at the end which i oversaw. thank you again for taking your time. i really appreciate your help!